# Delete elements with all letters in a list?

Tags: python

So I have:

```
letters = list(''.join(i) for i in permutations('A''B''C''D''E''F''G''H''J''K''M''N''P''Q''R''T''V''W''X''Y''Z''1''2''3''4''5''6''7''8''9''0', 3))
print(letters)
```

and it prints some combinations that are all letters or all numbers, or two numbers and a letter. I only want combinations with two letters and a number. Is there a way to delete all list elements don't contain just two letters and a number?

P.S. I'm a python newbie so please try to make answers understandable for me.

Comment: I think you can solve this by yourself because you already knew how to use iterator even itertools. So there seems no advice needed.

Answer (score 2):

You show only a little work, so I will just give hints. Work on these hints, and if you are not able to finish then show us your attempts and we can help you further.

Given your starting code, you apparently do not care about the order of your triples, and you want all permutations of the three items within the triple. It is better to generate just what you want rather than to generate more and remove what you don't want. Here is how you can use `itertools` to this.

For each triple, first choose a combination of 2 letters from the alphabet. Then choose one digit. Given those choices, permute those three items into all orders.

You can do each step above with `itertools` using `combinations`, `product`,  `permutations`, and a list comprehension. You could do this all in one statement by nesting these functions, or spread it out for readability. My preferred answer has two lines, with the first line using a generator comprehension to create a generator that is used in the second line. You should also create two constants, one to hold the alphabet and the other to hold the digits.

I doubt that you actually want to print out the entire resulting list, which has 19,500 strings in it.

Comment: Nice, clean answer.